# Chrome Developer Tools edit CSS on live site and save only changed element modifications

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to make a number of suggestions to CSS edits for a page and am using Chrome Developer Tools to modify the page elements. I was wondering if there is any way that I am able to get CDT to save just the modifications that I have made into a single css stylesheet as a kind of summary?

I know that I am able to create a workspace and map a hosted css file to a local file, however, from what I can gather, this just uses your local file in place of the hosted file and does not give me a summary of the specific changes that I've made. Any suggestions?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @Paulie_D I apologise if my post was off topic. I thought that it was relevant. I am happy to delete it if I am in the wrong place posting here.